# How can you know how many tabs are open in an user browser

Tags: usage-statistics

According [to this post](http://sixrevisions.com/infographs/firefox-statistics/)

a typical firefox user has 2-3 tabs open.

How can they say that ?

Does Mozilla receive user statistics from firefox?

Can you get this information using javascript ?

Can you get this information with other browsers ?

Comment: Good question. There must be some kind of internal auditing in place. However i doubt they would expose this info via the JS api. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, they do get certain user statistics, and I assume this is one of them.  You can't access this in regular content (web page) JavaScript, in any browser, as far as I know.